# Selenium Python - Trace call error while executing scripts

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

I am new to Selenium-Python and installing python for Selenium webdriver.

When I run sample script I am getting error **Traceback (most recent call last):**

Adding complete details about error.

`enter code here`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace\SeleniumLoginPage\Login\selenium\Test1\src\Test1\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I need to know is it due to setup issues or compatibility issues that I am getting this error. I have installed:

- Python 3.4 first
- Eclipse(Luna)
- PyDev.

Eclipse details:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

PyDev details:

- 3.8.0.201409251235

Environmental Variables are set for Python as: In system variables , in variable name 'Path'I have added following: C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;

Please let me know what do I miss here?